# How to do fileupload validation through javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi I wanna do a simple validation of file upload through javascript how do i do that?
I want to check the extension and the file size as well.

Comment: Check the [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do a file validation through JavaScript you need the FileAPI functions to be available in your browser which will leave your browser support to only the newest ones.

If that is what you want, here is a [quick tutorial to get you started](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/).